# Can you add a legend to a dc.js Bubble Chart?

Tags: legend, dc.js, bubble-chart

[Is it possible to make a legend for Bubble Chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26040335/is-it-possible-to-make-a-legend-for-bubble-chart#new-answer)

Somebody asked this question a few years ago, but I cannot find a good answer for it. Does anybody have an example of where they made a legend for a bubble chart using dc.js?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually add legend support to any chart which does not have it already by defining the `.legendables()` function. Although many charts (e.g. pie, line, bar, scatter, sunburst) support it, the default is to return an empty array.

One reason why it might not be defined is that a chart doesn't necessarily know which values to show. But presumably you do, so you can specify them manually.

As an example, I've put the bubble chart from the [dc.js stock example](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/) in a fiddle, and patched in `legendables` like this:

```
 yearlyBubbleChart.legendables = function() {
   return [500, 250, 0, -250, -500].map(function(v) { // 1
     return {
       chart: yearlyBubbleChart, // 2
       name: v, // 3
       color: yearlyBubbleChart.getColor({value: {absGain: v}}) // 4
     };
   });
 };
```

1. Give the specific values which you want to show in the legend
2. The legend needs a reference back to the chart
3. Specify the label for each value - I'm just using the value itself
4. Give a color. This is the most complicated part. You could just specify a color directly, but I think it's better to use the color function (scale) that the chart uses. This means you have to produce artificial data that looks like your group values. Here the `colorAccessor` expects to look at `d.value.absGain` so we build data that looks like that.

After this, adding the legend to the chart is completely normal:

```
 yearlyBubbleChart.legend(dc.legend().x(600).y(20));
```

[image: bubble chart with legend]

[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/zwsej3jd/15/)